# Liquid Stabilisation?

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation, collision

After recently starting liquid simulation, I wanted to know how to stabilise the liquid after it is poured into another object(collision object eg. cup). No matter how many extra frames I give it, there is always some jittering happening and the liquid keeps moving.
Thanks!

Comment: can u provide blend file?

Answer (score 2):

Animate the flip ratio and set it to 0 at the point where you want the liquid to start settling down.  The flip ratio changes how chaotic the liquid behaves.  You may also want to play with viscosity and diffusion, depending on what kind of liquid you're trying to get to settle down.

Comment: You could also use the APIC fluid method as it is calmer and better for realistic animations